# make an android app autostart

Tags: android, autostart

Is it possible to make an installed app auto start itself?

thanks

Comment: But that's probably a bad practice, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Yes .

For this you have to use Alarm Notification .

You can found many tutorial for this on Net. Just google it..

You will found code something like this...

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, MyBroadcastListener.class);

            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(FirstScreen.this,
                    0, intent, 0);

            // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

            // Schedule the alarm!
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

The BroadCastListener You will set can call any activity in return. of own app too..:)

Answer (score 0):

Auto Start on any event? Check the `IntentFilter` out to make your app default for particular actions.

Auto Start on/after a particular time? check `Alarm` out!